# Onkeypress - how to use different numbers to trigger specific videos

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, keypress, onkeypress

Creating an interactive webpage where I want videos to play when a user presses the number keys. Each time a user presses key "1", a certain video will play, when they press key "2" a different video plays.

Right now I am only able to have one video be triggered at a time in javascript, my "1" key turns on the first video, but when I add a second video with the javascript using "2" key, only the second video works by pressing "2", the "1" no longer activates the first video.

here is my html and java

```
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <video id="vid" src="video/IMG_8873.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>

  <video id="ocean" src="video/OCEAN_8873.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</html>


JAVASCRIPT

var video = document.getElementById('vid');

document.onkeypress = function(e) {
  console.log(e)
  if (e.key === "1" ) {
   { video.paused ? video.play() : video.pause(); }
  }
};



var video = document.getElementById('ocean');

document.onkeypress = function(f) {
  console.log(f)
  if (f.key === "2" ) {
   { video.paused ? video.play() : video.pause(); }
  }
};
```

Comment: `var video = document.getElementById('ocean');` overwrites the first video. Either put them into their own enclosure (Wrapping them in a function, or using `let` within curly brackets), or use a different variable name (ie. video2).

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding your event handler with your second callback.

Change your code to read:

```
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
  console.log(e)
  if (e.key === "1" ) {
   var video = document.getElementById('vid');
   video.paused ? video.play() : video.pause();
  } else if (e.key === "2" ) {
   var video = document.getElementById('ocean');
   video.paused ? video.play() : video.pause(); 
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you!! It works I think I just messed up by changing the "e" to "f" when it should still be "e" in the code

Comment: I want to add a function so that when I press "1" the video will appear instead of already being in the background and just playing when pressed. I could also do this by changing the videos opacity from 0%-100% when opening, just need some coding help. Here is the code I have now